# zsh: command not found: subl

Tags: zsh, ubuntu-18.04, sublimetext, zshrc

I switched my ubuntu shell from bash to zsh.
Everything works fine and base commands like ls are actually working. 
But the problem is that my installed apps like Sublime-text and VScode aren't found at all. 
I type `subl program.c` and get the following response: `zsh: command not found: subl`
I type `which subl` and get the following response: `subl not found`

Here's my .zshrc file:

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
...
export ZSH="/home/kianoush/.oh-my-zsh"
...
ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"
...
plugins=(git zsh-autosuggestions)
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
...
export PATH="/usr/local/man:$PATH"
```

I tried redefining the PATH variable but probably I'm doing it wrong.
I have the same problem with other apps like VScode.

Comment: If you start up bash and run `which subl`, what are the results?

Comment: `subl not found`

Comment: In either `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`, you have an assignment to `PATH` that added the directory containing `subl` to your `PATH` variable. You need to make a similar assignment in `.zshrc`.

Comment: @NoushKia : Where in the code you posted, do you add the subl-directory to the PATH variable? If you don#t want to do this, you could instead define an alias or function named `subl`, which invokes your editor by providing the explicit path. In particular for a directory, which contains only one executable, this would be for me the preferred way, but of course this is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by inputting the following commands in my terminal:

`sudo ln -s /snap/sublime-text/109/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text /usr/local/bin/subl`

Note that I installed sublime using snap. For versions installed using apt you should probably use the following command:

`sudo ln -s /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text /usr/local/bin/subl`

Basically, just find your sublime_text files and link them to /usr/local/bin/subl